# Allow Nulls into a List<DateTime> but exclude nulls in Min.Date()

Tags: c#, linq, list, datetime

I'm trying to populate a List<> with dates but allow Nulls because the data source can contain nulls for the date. This is the code I tried this:

```
List<Nullable<DateTime>> DateList = new List<Nullable<DateTime>>();


    for (int ii = 0; ii < queryresults.Count; ii++)
    {

        object o = queryresults[ii].Fields[SplitComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()].Value;

        if (o is DateTime)
        {
            DateList.Add((DateTime)o);
        }
        else
        {
            DateList.Add(null);
        }
    }
}        

var firstDay = DateList.Min().Date;
var results =
    DateList
      .GroupBy(x => x.Date.Subtract(firstDay).Days / 7 + 1)
      .SelectMany(gx => gx, (gx, x) => new {Week = gx.Key,DateTime = x,Count = gx.Count(),});
```

But now the .Min().Date doesn't work.

**Edit**

My main goal is to be able to pull all the datetime values from a column from a collection. Find the Min().Date and Group the datetimes based on the Min().Date by week starting from the Min().Date

This is what I came up with basically, iterate through the collection, put all the datetimes into a datelist, find the min and groupthem to find the week. I need the null values as placeholders because what I'll eventually do is output each value back to the collection, so I know what week that datetime was in, in relation the min.date

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are no dates in the list?  What should `firstDay` be?

Comment: Sigh... guys, put the lamda *in* the `Min()` call... every LINQ step has a cost associated with it, don't just assume it will automagically get resolved into a beautiful expression tree (that's an oxymoron, BTW - expression trees are never beautiful)...

Comment: RIght on, @code4life.  For that matter, the `if` block is much more code than needed.  `DateList.Add(o as DateTime?);` would suffice.

Comment: @recursive I have a default value for firstday that I ommited from the code.

Comment: I'm basically applying this groupby and count to each row I get from my datasource collection and spitting it back out as an additional column. I don' t know if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: @Sewder: why are you even adding in the null dates? I'm looking at your logic and here's what you're doing: 1) add in all the null dates. 2) ignore them in the final output.  You're loading the gun, aiming at your toes, and pulling the trigger here, man. Do yourself a favor and do this instead: `if (!(o is DateTime)) continue;`

Comment: @code4life They're to be used as place holders. The groupby and count values are added as column to my collection and then outputted. If I don't have the Nulls then when I loop through the resuls, I get an out of range exception because i omitted the nulls.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
var firstDay = DateList.Where(d => d != null).Cast<DateTime>().Min().Date;
```

Filter out the null values, cast the remaining to regular `DateTime`.

**Edit:** You can do it before the groupby too:

```
var filtered = DateList.Where(d => d != null).Cast<DateTime>().ToList();
var firstDay = filtered.Min().Date;
var results = filtered.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Subtract(firstDay).Days / 7 + 1)
                      ...
```

But I'm wondering why you need the nulls in your list in the first place? Just create a `List<DateTime>` and add the values that aren't null.

Comment: Now the GroupBy line is throwing this exception : Line Error CS1061 'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assemb

Comment: Well yeh, your list hasn't changed, do you really need the null values? Seems to me you should just filter them out before the GroupBy

Comment: Well, I need the null values as place holders because I'll be eventually spitting them back out to the datasource. So If I have 80 values, 10 are nulls, I want to be able to spit out 80 values not 70.  I just tried it and I got an exception for out of range.

Comment: What I'm doing is applying the group values to each row from my datasource collection, and then outputting it again into a datagridview as a column.

Answer (score 1):

Filter null values in the collection/List by looking `HasValue` property.

```
DateList.Where(d=>d.HasValue).Min();
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i9shP4)

Comment: `.Where(d => d.HasValue).Min().Date` still won't compile though

Comment: It can't throw, because it won't compile.

Comment: It should compile, see attached demo.

Comment: The attached demo has different code.  I now understand what you meant, but there's a `.Value` missing somewhere in this answer.

Comment: I modified rest of the code for you, check now complete demo.